# Module not found error in Component file on running Mocha Test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, path, mocha.js

I have a Mocha Test. The test works fine normally if the component file doesn't have any imports like '../../'. Somehow the paths are not by test properly.

Example below

**IconComponent.js**

//It's failing here in this line

***import something from '../../somewhere';***

export default function Icon() {

}

**icon.test.js**

import Icon from './IconComponent';

**Test Command**

"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --require @babel/register --require ./scripts/dom.js '**/**/*.test.js' --exclude '**/node_modules/**'"